# Cloudera Docker image ... everything errors out

Tags: hadoop, docker, cloudera

I am running a 16 GB Macbook pro with El Capitan OS. I installed the cloudera docker image using

```
docker pull cloudera/quickstart:latest
docker run --privileged=true --hostname=quickstart.cloudera -t -i 9f3ab06c7554 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

the image boots fine, and I can see most services starting up

```
Started Hadoop historyserver:                              [  OK  ]
starting nodemanager, logging to /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-nodemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started Hadoop nodemanager:                                [  OK  ]
starting resourcemanager, logging to /var/log/hadoop-yarn/yarn-yarn-resourcemanager-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started Hadoop resourcemanager:                            [  OK  ]
starting master, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-master-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started HBase master daemon (hbase-master):                [  OK  ]
starting rest, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-rest-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started HBase rest daemon (hbase-rest):                    [  OK  ]
starting thrift, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-thrift-quickstart.cloudera.out
Started HBase thrift daemon (hbase-thrift):                [  OK  ]
Starting Hive Metastore (hive-metastore):                  [  OK  ]
Started Hive Server2 (hive-server2):                       [  OK  ]
Starting Sqoop Server:                                     [  OK  ]
Sqoop home directory: /usr/lib/sqoop2
```

Some failures as well

```
Failure to start Spark history-server (spark-history-server[FAILED]n value: 1
Starting Hadoop HBase regionserver daemon: starting regionserver, logging to /var/log/hbase/hbase-hbase-regionserver-quickstart.cloudera.out
hbase-regionserver.
Starting hue:                                              [FAILED]
```

But once the bootup is complete, if I try to run anything it fails

for example trying to run spark-shell

```
[root@quickstart /]# spark-shell
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000b0000000, 357892096, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 357892096 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid3113.log
```

or trying to run hive shell

```
[root@quickstart /]# hive
Unable to determine Hadoop version information.
'hadoop version' returned:
Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.5.0 Subversion http://github.com/cloudera/hadoop -r fd21232cef7b8c1f536965897ce20f50b83ee7b2 Compiled by jenkins on 2015-11-09T20:37Z Compiled with protoc 2.5.0 From source with checksum 98e07176d1787150a6a9c087627562c This command was run using /usr/jars/hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar
[root@quickstart /]#
```

My question is what can I do so that I can run the spark-shell and the hive shell successfully?

Comment: What is your host operating system?

Comment: mac osx el capitan. 16 GB physical memory on my machine

Comment: That resolved the problem. I did a `docker-machine stop default` then I went to virtual box and bumped up the memory to 8 GB. Now I started `docker-machine start default` and ran the quickstart container. Now Hive and Spark-shell spark successfully.

Comment: perhaps you should respond as an answer rather than comment so that I can mark your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running Docker on a Mac, Docker runs under VirtualBox, not directly with the Mac's memory. (Same thing would happen in Windows).

You probably wouldn't get these errors on a Linux host since Docker isn't virtualized there.

The Cloudera quickstart vm recommends 8Gb of memory to run all the services and the docker vm is only 512Mb, I think.

The solution would be to stop the docker-machine instance, open VirtualBox, and increase the memory size of the "default" VM to the necessary amount.